# input file or path doesn't exist when executing scala script

Tags: scala

I just started learning Spark/Scala, here is a confusing issue I came across on my very first practice:

1. I created a test file: input.txt in /etc/spark/bin
2. I created a RDD
3. I started to do a word count but received the error saying `Input path does not exist`

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Why the input.txt not picked up by Scala? if it is permission related, the file was created by root but I am also running Spark/Scala under root.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Spark reads file from `hdfs`. Copy it with:

```
hadoop fs -put /etc/spark/bin/input.txt /hdfs/path
```

If it's a local installation file will be moved to `hadoop` folder.